# How to free up Spark worker container memory after jobs finish

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am running spark standalone in Kubernetes, I have a pyspark application that connects to the master using SparkSession. The app is loading around 4gb json files and does some SQL queries.

If I restart the workers, they use around 400/500mb RAM on the worker container, I start my application and the memory goes up to around 4/5GB, after the application finishes the memory only seems to drop by around 1GB. How can I get the worker to release all its memory.

My app is not caching or persisting any dataframes.

My problem is that my app runs hourly, after x number of runs the worker pods restart and the job will lost connection until it switches to a new worker.

You can see in the Grafana graph below.

[image]

Comment: try using `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled true`

Comment: Spark docs describe `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled` as `Enable periodic cleanup of worker / application directories` I'm not sure this will resolve my issue.

Comment: @SamCulley did you figure out the solution, I am facing the same issue